# How to cache in IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, r, ipython, knitr, jupyter-notebook

Environment:

- Python 3
- IPython 3.2

Every time I shut down a IPython notebook and re-open it, I have to re-run all the cells. But some cells involve intensive computation.

By contrast, `knitr` in R save the results in a cache directory by default so only new code and new settings would invoke computation.

I looked at `ipycache` but it seems to cache a cell instead of the notebook. Is there a counterpart of cache of `knitr` in IPython?

Comment: I don't know if there is such capability in Ipython, but you could simply cache your expensive computations to disk with for instance [joblib.Memory](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/memory.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? When I run something in an IPython Notebook that is expensive I almost always write it to disk afterword. For example, if my data is a list of JSON object, I write it to disk as line separated JSON formatted strings:

```
with open('path_to_file.json', 'a') as file:
    for item in data: 
        line = json.dumps(item)
        file.write(line + '\n')
```

You can then read back in the data the same way:

```
data = []
with open('path_to_file.json', 'a') as file:
    for line in file: 
        data_item = json.loads(line)
        data.append(data_item)
```

I think this is a good practice generally speaking because it provides you a backup. You can also use pickle for the same thing. If your data is really big you can actually `gzip.open` to directly write to a zip file.

**EDIT**

To save a scikit learn model to disk use `joblib.pickle`.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
km.fit(some_data)


from sklearn.externals import joblib
# dump to pickle
joblib.dump(km, 'model.pkl')

# and reload from pickle
km = joblib.load('model.pkl')
```

Comment: I tried applying machine learning models to datasets. For example, I import some data (a few hundred MB) by pandas, and then train and test two models by scikit-learn. I want to "cache" all intermediate transformed DataFrame, as well as the trained models. So I can "carry on" experiments on the intermediate DataFrame without reading from the ground.

Comment: @zelong ok, you should use `joblib` to pickle your `sklearn` models. See my edit above.

And to write your dataframes to disk just use `dataframe.to_csv('yourfile.csv)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The pickling of scikit-learn model looks quite good. I tried quite a few wrangling with DataFrames and it seems demanding to save a bunch of intermediate DataFrame to csv files. But it seems IPython has not provide a counterpart of `RData` cache, which put everything in a single cube.

Comment: I removed the `file.close()` calls, because `with` [closes files for you](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Also: since `data` is a "list", one could more simply do `json.dump(data, file)`, without any loop. And similarly `json.load(file)`.

Comment: Finally, naming something `file` is officially not recommended: it clobbers the built-in `file` type.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there is something as convenient as an automatic cache. The `%store` magic option is close, but requires you to do the caching and reloading manually and explicitly.

## In your Jupyter notebook:

```
a = 1
%store a
```

Now, let's say you close the notebook and the kernel gets restarted. You no longer have access to the local variables. However, you *can* reload the variables you've stored using the `-r` option.

```
%store -r a
print a # Should print 1
```

Comment: Does this work between two different notebooks? Seems to be the case

Answer (score 7):

In fact the functionality you ask is already there, no need to re-implement it manually by doing your dumps .

You can use the use the %store or maybe better the %%cache magic (extension) to store the results of these intermittently cells, so they don't have to be recomputed (see https://github.com/rossant/ipycache)

It is as simple as:

```
%load_ext ipycache
```

Then, in a cell e.g.:

```
%%cache mycache.pkl var1 var2
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
```

> When you execute this cell the first time, the code is executed, and
>   the variables var1 and var2 are saved in mycache.pkl in the current
>   directory along with the outputs. Rich display outputs are only saved
>   if you use the development version of IPython. When you execute this
>   cell again, the code is skipped, the variables are loaded from the
>   file and injected into the namespace, and the outputs are restored in
>   the notebook.

It saves all graphics, output produced, and all the variables specified automatically for you :)

Comment: Extremely useful, and easier to get working for me than `%autoreload` (my other way of hacking around changing modules but not wanting to reload data
)

Comment: `ipycache` seems to need a lot of love. Warnings galore, and last update May 2016.

Comment: Damn, it used to be low maintenance :S I guess things change as  python versions progress... Still have some good memories, and the best solution I've found so far, would be great to find something better/more active

Comment: What is the difference with `%store`?

Comment: Haven't really used `%store` (but now plan to :) ) It really has been a while I used `ipycache`... If memory holds, It saved all graphics printouts etc. of a cell along with values of variables. Also, you just had to say a cell is cached, and the output variables. It used cached if the cell was not edited from the time of caching, can do multiple variables, can define variables that if changed cache is invalidated etc. It was not perfect but would really like to see something like it again.

Comment: `ipycache` is no longer maintained, do you know another tool?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [cache magic](https://pypi.org/project/ipython-cache/).

> ```
> %cache myVar = someSlowCalculation(some, "parameters")
> ```
>
> This will calculate someSlowCalculation(some, "parameters") once. And in subsequent calls it restores myVar from storage.

https://pypi.org/project/ipython-cache/

Under the hood it does pretty much the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: When does a cached variable get invalidated? Ideally it would invalidated when the variables that it depends upon changes but that seems kind clever.

Comment: per default it changes when the string right of the "=" changes. So it changes when method or its direct parameters change, but it does not look into the methods or the values of the parameters

Comment: Oooh, that sounds likely precisely what I want.

Comment: Hmm there was no cache invalidation when I just tested this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install any additional packages, there is a very simple solution using python's [builtin `shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shelve.html), which acts like a persistent `dict` object. Since the shelve lives in a file on disk, it also survives restarts. It can't be accessed from multiple kernels at once though, because the [underlying DBM database](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dbm.html) does not support concurrent access.

We can define a simple wrapper function that will fetch the result of an expensive computation from the shelve if it is found:

```py
# Notebook cell to define the cache function
import shelve
_cache_database_filename = 'MyNotebookName.ipynb.cacheDB'

def cache(variable_name: str, get_value_lazy: callable):
    global _cache_database, _cache_database_filename
    if '_cache_database' not in globals():
        _cache_database = shelve.open(_cache_database_filename)
    if variable_name not in _cache_database:
        _cache_database[variable_name] = get_value_lazy()  # Not in cache, compute value
    return _cache_database[variable_name]
```

To use it, you wrap your long-running calculations with `cache('variable_name', lambda: ...)`. The `lambda` is there so that the calculation is only executed lazily if the requested variable is not in the cache. Otherwise it would be computed before calling `cache`, which defeats the purpose.

```py
# Notebook cell that performs some long calculation:
def expensive_calculation(x): return len(str(x ** x))

# Instead of:
#my_result = expensive_calculation(100000)
# You write:
my_result = cache('my_result', lambda: expensive_calculation(100000))
```

The first time you run this cell, it will take several seconds to run `expensive_calculation(100000)` and save the result to the file `MyNotebookName.ipynb.cacheDB`. When you re-run the cell, even after restarting the Jupyter kernel, it will load the result from the cache database:

```py
In [2]: def expensive_calculation(x): return len(str(x ** x))

In [3]: %time a = cache('a', lambda: expensive_calculation(100000))
CPU times: user 3.64 s, sys: 9.48 ms, total: 3.65 s
Wall time: 3.69 s

In [4]: %time a = cache('a', lambda: expensive_calculation(100000))
CPU times: user 58 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 58 µs
Wall time: 65.8 µs

In [5]: del _cache_database['a']  # Remove an entry from cache

In [6]: %time a = cache('a', lambda: expensive_calculation(100000))
CPU times: user 3.67 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.67 s
Wall time: 3.66 s

In [7]: quit
```

Starting a new `ipython` session:

```py
In [1]: def cache...

In [2]: def expensive_calculation(x): return len(str(x ** x))

In [3]: %time a = cache('a', lambda: expensive_calculation(100000))
CPU times: user 2.63 ms, sys: 617 µs, total: 3.24 ms
Wall time: 3.25 ms
```