# Where are saved the data of my Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebooks to code in Python and was wondering where was stored the "temporary" data I generate during the execution. Indeed, it's huge amount of data and seems to alter the efficiency of my laptop. Moereover my browser (GoogleChrome) seems to suffer from a lack of memory.

Another question I was asking is how to save a Jupyter Notebook session for quite a long time. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342155/how-to-pickle-or-store-jupyter-ipython-notebook-session-for-later) but the accepted answer got quite few votes so I was wondering how reliable it was. Again, what about the memory this operation needs and where are the data stored during that time?

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter notebook stores the temporary results in your Laptops RAM. If the memory is full, usually the system starts to write a swap file (or starts to fill swap partition on Linux). This greatly influences the performance of the system since certain system parts are swaped to the much slower SSD/HDD and are read back into the RAM when you start using them again.

I don't think it is possible to store the whole notebook state. You can try to pickle everything thats picklable and read it back as a workaround (as suggested in the post you mention). When you save a notebook, all plots and outputs are stored by default but you will have to rerun the notebook if you want to change something.

Comment: Thanks but what does `dill`package, by consequence ?