# Is there any way for dumping all the context variables to a file?

Tags: python, dump

Is there any way for dumping all the context variables to a file, then after a restart of the computer, and reload all the context variables and continue the execution from where left?

Comment: You could probably pickle the `globals()` but I'm not really sure this is the path you want to go down. As it stands, it's not so clear to me what you need.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't made my question clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342155/how-to-pickle-or-store-jupyter-ipython-notebook-session-for-later, a similar question

Answer (score 0):

You might find [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) interesting if you're looking to work interactively and save your state.