# Trouble pickling a list in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pickle, python-class

so I created a book class and added its instances to a list that I'm trying to pickle but I'm getting a strange error. Help appreciated!

```
with open("book_data/books.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(book_list, f)
```

Output:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-45ad0cec62df> in <module>
      1 with open("book_data/books.pkl", "wb") as f:
      2 
----> 3         pickle.dump(book_list, f)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.book'>: it's not the same object as __main__.book
```

Comment: @will_f the books are instances of the book class, `class book:
    def __init__(self,title,author,genre,description,rating,nbratings,nbpages):
        self.title=title
        self.author=author
        self.genre=genre
        self.description=description
        self.rating=rating
        self.nbratings=nbratings
        self.nbpages=nbpages ` here is an example instance: `b=book(t,a,g,d,r,nbr,nbp)`
    `book_list.append(b)`, btw I did the same thing using pycharm and it worked just fine. It seems that the issue is exclusive to Jupyter...

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985430/11305111) might help

Comment: @jayveesea that's pretty handy but it gave me a recursion error when I tried it, `RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5011bc09ef45> in <module>
      1 import dill
----> 2 dill.dump_session('Data_Gathering.db')`

Comment: [`%store`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) is another solution which I have used in the past.  `%store someVar` and then `%store -r` to retrieve.